# Horizontal UIScrollView on Panorama

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, panoramas

I want to have a `UIScrollView` on a panoramic image so that you can pan across the image horizontally. For some reason, the code I'm using does not allow the user to scroll horizontally.

Why won't it scroll horizontally?

Here is the code:

```
  [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,160,1338,269)];
  scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIImageView *panorama = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1338, 269)];
panorama.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Panorama.png"];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 269);
[scrollView addSubview:panorama];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollView's `frame` is stationary, the `contentSize` is the one that allows the scrolling.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 269);
```

Should be replaced with

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1338, 269);
```

To allow a large `contentSize` to be scrolled through.  The frame should be smaller.

```
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 269);
```

Think of the `frame` as the area that you see on the screen at any given time. Think of the `contentSize` as the area that the scrollView is capable of showing (much larger).

Comment: @user3161730 no Problem. I have always had trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it other way around. Scroll view's content size must be set to the size of the large image you are trying to scroll.

Change contentsize to size of the uiimageview and change scrollview frame to 320,269